# json-server doesn't show db.json file from atom editor on windows 10

Tags: atom-editor, json-server

I'm trying to create REST api for my next project wit json-server and atom on windows 10. But when I call windows cmd for watching db.json its shows 
  Oops, db.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating db.json with some default data....
Please tell me how?